# Add a contextual menu item in xcode (plugin)

Tags: xcode, swift, plugins, contextmenu

Im trying to add an item to an existing contextual menu in xcode. So far ive managed to add an item to ALL contextual menus opposed to a specific one.I am using "NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification.object"to reference the menu object, but not sure this is the correct way to go. code below. any ideas??

Thanks a lot!

```
import AppKit

var sharedPlugin: plugin?

 class plugin: NSObject {

var bundle: NSBundle
lazy var center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

// object holding all notifications:
var notificationSet = NSMutableSet();


class func pluginDidLoad(bundle: NSBundle) {
    let appName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? NSString
    if appName == "Xcode" {
        sharedPlugin = plugin(bundle: bundle)
    }
}

init(bundle: NSBundle) {
    self.bundle = bundle
    self.notificationSet = NSMutableSet()


    super.init()

// see name: "NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification":

    center.addObserver(self, selector:    #selector(self.createMenuItems), name:"NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification", object: nil)


}

deinit {
    removeObserver()
}

func removeObserver() {
    center.removeObserver(self)
}

func createMenuItems(notification: NSNotification) {

// checking what pops up the context menu when right clicking the console:

    if (!(self.notificationSet).containsObject(notification.name)) {
        print(notification.name)
        print(notification.object?.className)
    self.notificationSet.addObject(notification.name);
        let menu = notification.object;

  //creating menu item 'testing' :

        let menuItem = NSMenuItem(title:"testing", action:#selector(self.doMenuAction), keyEquivalent:"");
        menuItem.target = self

 //adding item to context menu:

        menu!.addItem(menuItem)

        let actionMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title:"Do Action", action:#selector(self.doMenuAction), keyEquivalent:"")
        actionMenuItem.target = self


    }
}

func doMenuAction() {

    print("hi")

    self.notificationSet.removeAllObjects()
}
```

}